# Server-side Changes to Model not Reflected in UI - EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm persisting my model from my controller via a call to this.get('model').save(). This results in a PUT to an endpoint that just returns a 200 message and nothing further. On the server side however, some custom rules are in place that are changing the data so that it's different than what Ember sent to the server. This puts my UI and my persistence tier into an inconsistent state.

What's the correct way to make sure the UI reflects what the correct state of the data after it was persisted to the server? Should my server-side endpoint return the updated model? I've tried just calling this.get('model').reload() after the save() but the UI isn't updating. When I did this I could see that it's asking and getting the new model from the server but as I said, it's not reflected in the UI.

I feel like there's some knowledge fundamental to Ember that I'm missing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your api endpoint should return the updated model that matches the structure of what you sent to the server for update. If there are hasMany relationships at play, you may have an issue with your serializer or ember model... You shouldn't have to reload the model. If you do, you may have a problem with model bindings throughout your app.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are not waiting for the record to complete the updating process.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

So this would be:

```
this.get('model').reload().then(function() {
  console.log("Now I am ready !");
})
```

Always remember that javascript is async.

Comment: To build on what htache is saying, you would want to put your this.get('model').reload() iside that 'then' block.

Comment: Yeah this is effectively what I'm doing. The then() block of my save() call has the reload() call inside it. Do I need to do anything within the then() block of the reload() call to get the UI to update? I thought the data-binding nature of Ember would result in the UI updating whenever the model changed but that doesn't seem to be the case right now.

Comment: Why does he need to reload the model?